# ON clause in HIVE (for version < 0.14)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have tried running below query in Hive but it is showing following **error: 
" Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'eff_start_dt'** ". I think there is a problem with ON clause in below hive query. 
I have tried running the same query on Teradata and it runs perfectly fine.
So my question is:

> What all alzebraic expression we can use in 'ON' clause in hive?
>   How can I make my below query run in hive?

```
SELECT
q.calendar_dt               as  calendar_dt         ,
x.corp_id                   as  corp_id             ,
x.mkt_cd                    as  mkt_cd              ,
x.bill_curr_cd              as  bill_curr_cd        
FROM
corpmis_daily_time_dim as q   
  INNER JOIN  corpmis_daily_global_corp_daily_expsr as x   
  INNER JOIN   (select max(eff_start_dt) as max_eff_start_dt from corpmis_daily_global_corp_daily_expsr)  as  y
ON
q.calendar_dt between x.eff_start_dt and x.eff_end_dt  WHERE 
  q.calendar_dt <=  y.max_eff_start_dt;
```

Comment: MySQL is complaining that your reference to `eff_start_dt` within the subquery aliased `y` is ambiguous, because it is unqualified and could refer either to: that from the `corpmis_daily_global_corp_daily_expsr` table used within the subquery; or that of the same table aliased `x` in the outer query.  You should resolve the ambiguity by qualifying the column (with a table prefix).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have removed all 'as' in FROM clause. And did this in the last join table: 
(select max(a.eff_start_dt) as max_eff_start_dt from corpmis_daily_global_corp_daily_expsr a)  y

And now it is working fine.

Comment: So, conclusion is: Never use 'as' in the FROM clause in hive. And always use aiases for tables so as to avoid error and confusion in hive.

Comment: I'm not sure what `as` you removed, or why—but that wasn't the problem.  The other changes you made are what fixed your issue; and yes, always table-qualifying column references avoids any possible ambiguity.

Comment: For that 'as' part(in FROM clause), it works perfectly fine in MySQL or Teradata. But it doesen't work in hive. This is what i was trying to say.